# How do you find the record type of an input in Clojure?

Tags: class, types, clojure, record

I can't figure out how to do something like (instance? MyRecordType x) when MyRecordType was declared using defrecord. The type and class of the records are always clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap.

For instance:

```
(defrecord MyRecord1 [data-field1 data-field2])
(defrecord MyRecord2 [data-field1])
(def x (->MyRecord1 1 2))
(def y (->MyRecord2 3))
(instance? MyRecord1 x)
 => false
(instance? MyRecord2 y)
 => false
(type x)
 => clojure.lang.IPersistentMap
(class y)
 => clojure.lang.IPersistentMap
(= (type x) (type y))
 => true
```

Comment: What version of Clojure are you using? This works for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work that way. This is what your example looks like on Clojure 1.5.1

```
user=> (defrecord MyRecord1 [data-field1 data-field2])
user=> (defrecord MyRecord2 [data-field1])
user=> (def x (->MyRecord1 1 2))
user=> (def y (->MyRecord2 3))
user=> (instance? MyRecord1 x)
true
user=> (instance? MyRecord2 y)
true
user=> (type x)
user.MyRecord1
user=> (class y)
user.MyRecord2
user=> (= (type x) (type y))
false
```

Comment: Upon returning to this question, I can no longer reproduce the problem. I know I was getting some form of what the original question claimed, but this is what I'm now getting in a clean repl and also in a unit test. Sorry for the noise as it must have been user error but I appreciate the extra sets of eyes.